# Is that style of FSM is correct and synthesible?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Talking about only the state function here, is there any problem here ? not using "next state" and only use 1 state "rd_state" that can take 2 values "IDLE_RD" and "RD_TRAN"?

```
 always @(posedge clk)
    begin : rd_state_func
        if (reset==1) begin
            rd_state<=IDLE_RD;
        end else begin
            case (rd_state) 
                IDLE_RD: begin
                        if (pkt_req==1) begin
                            if (fifo_empty==0) begin
                                rd_state <= RD_TRAN;
                            end else begin
                                rd_state <= IDLE_RD;
                            end
                        end else begin
                            rd_state <= IDLE_RD;
                        end
                        end
                RD_TRAN: begin
                        if (some_if.eop==1) begin 
                            rd_state <= IDLE_RD;
                        end else begin
                            rd_state <= RD_TRAN;
                        end
                end
            endcase
        end
    end
```

Comment: It's basically OK, but the lines that assign the same state are not necessary. So, in the branch `IDLE_RD:`, you don't need either `d_state <= IDLE_RD;` and the associated `else`s, `begin`s and `end`s. Likewise, in the branch `RD_TRAN:`, you don't need `d_state <= RD_TRAN;` etc.

Comment: usually people split FSM in 2 or 3 parts: combinational, sequential (and output).  1 part (as in your case) is ok for a small FSM. There is an interesting reading about it: http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2003SJ_SystemVerilogFSM.pdf

Answer (score 0):

It is correct.

It is synthesizable (why wouldn't?).

But it might not to be the best style.

I tend to use that precisely style. I find it to be useful when maintaining and debugging large FSMs, such as the ones that come from the translation of a sequential algorithm.

OTOH, synthesizers seem to detect better a two or three "always" style FSMs and tend to produce a better result (less gates). This is because this style don't rely on a given datapath, but the datapath must be inferred by the synthesizer (for each register, the synthesizer must determine which signals are routed to its input and calculate the equations that determine which of the routed signals must enter the register). I thought this should be straightforward, but I've found that it's not the case. Some FSMs which XST synthesizes correctly, don't work in Quartus, and viceversa.